# ASP.NET Calendar control: HowTo stop resetting calendar when navigating Back in the browser

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I've implemented the ASP.NET Calendar control. I'm using it to show events happening in the area.

THE PROBLEM

Today is August 18th, so when the calendar loads, August is selected as the current month. If I navigate to say October, and then navigate to another page and then try to go back to the page with the Calendar by clicking the browser Back button, the Calendar resets back to August, instead of remaining at October.

Can anyone recommend how I may circumvent this?

Thanks!

Comment: I just had a thought... which calendar control is this?  Is it the standard ASP.Net calendar control, or is it the AJAX Calendar control?

Comment: Sorry didn't see this comment until now. It's the standard one, and it acts an an Event Calendar, meaning that it's not a dropdown styled calendar, it's actually a full html rendered calendar taking up most of the page where I can see all my events inside each individual day square.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute to the calendar definition in the HTML part of the page?

```
EnableViewState="true"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that this evening and see if that does the trick. I'll respond back to let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. I also ensured that I enabled the Viewstate for the page, and handled the IsPostBack.

Any other ideas? Has anyone succeeded in doing this?

Answer (score -1):

What you described is how it should happen, as when you click the back button, the page is loaded as a fresh page nothing wrong with that.

What you can try:

- is to save the month and the date selected, to a Cookie file or "session variables" or "global variable" while navigating away from page
- on page load, "try" to set the values of month and date to what is stored in the let's say "session variable".